# Subqueries for individual fields create multiple records

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata

My scenario: there can be multiple (up to 3) rejection codes for a request. The first one is the primary rejection code, and the secondary (second and third) rejection codes are optional. To determine the rejection_code ranking, there is a field called rejection_rowId. If rejection_rowId = '1', then it's the primary rejection. If rejection_rowId = '2', then it's the second rejection. If it's '3', it's the third. Now, I'm trying to display all rejection_code values belonging to one request in one record, rather than storing 1 record for each rejection_code. I'm running into trouble and was wondering if anyone could shed some light into why my SQL isn't working correctly.

My SQL looks basically like this;

```
SELECT DISTINCT rea.id
    ,(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '1'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection1

    ,(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '2'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection2

    ,(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '3'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection3

FROM reason rea
INNER JOIN rejection rej ON rea.rowId = rej.rowId
WHERE rea.id = '12345';
```

The output generated by the above SQL is...

```
id    | rejection1 | rejection2 | rejection3
12345 | 26         | NULL       | NULL
12345 | NULL       | 51         | NULL
12345 | NULL       | NULL       | 3
```

The output I'm trying (and failing) to generate is...

```
id    | rejection1 | rejection2 | rejection3
12345 | 26         | 51         | 3
```

If anyone can help me identify and fix the problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  rea.id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rej.rejection_rowId = '1' THEN rej.rejection_code END) AS rejection1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rej.rejection_rowId = '2' THEN rej.rejection_code END) AS rejection2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rej.rejection_rowId = '3' THEN rej.rejection_code END) AS rejection3,
FROM
  reason rea
  INNER JOIN rejection rej ON rea.rowId = rej.rowId
WHERE
  rea.id = '12345'
GROUP BY rea.id
```

There is no need to join between the same tables again and again and using subquery to achieve what you need is simply not necessary and **costs a lot**.

With the `GROUP BY` clause you limit your result to one row. With condition inside aggregate function you only display the rejection in the column when there actually was one and you are able to split them into separate columns.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This did the trick. I tried using case statements earlier, but I didn't think of using an aggregate function and a group by statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

For sums:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rea.id
    ,SUM(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '1'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection1

    ,SUM(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '2'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection2

    ,SUM(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '3'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection3

FROM reason rea
INNER JOIN rejection rej ON rea.rowId = rej.rowId
WHERE rea.id = '12345'
GROUP BY rea.id ;
```

For max:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rea.id
    ,MAX(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '1'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection1

    ,MAX(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '2'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection2

    ,MAX(SELECT rejection_code 
      FROM rejection t1
      INNER JOIN reason t2 ON t1.rowId = t2.rowId
      WHERE t1.rejection_rowId = '3'
        AND t1.rowId = REA.rowId) AS rejection3

FROM reason rea
INNER JOIN rejection rej ON rea.rowId = rej.rowId
WHERE rea.id = '12345'
GROUP BY rea.id ;
```